# Procfile Heroku

Tags: python, heroku, procfile

I tried to deploy my first Telegram chatbot (done with Chatterbot library) on Heroku. The files of my chatbot are:
requirements (txt file)
Procfile (worker: python magghybot.py)
botusers (csv file)
Magghy (py file)
magghybot (py file)
runtime (txt file)
telegramtoken (txt file)
conversations (yml file in folder named lang)
math_words (json file in folder named lang)

When I tried to deploy through terminal  I have this result:

```
Counting objects: 14, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (8/8), done.
Writing objects: 100% (14/14), 5.27 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 14 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote: 
remote: -----> Python app detected
remote:  !     Warning: Your application is missing a Procfile. This file tells Heroku how to run your application.
remote:  !     Learn more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
remote: -----> Installing python-2.7.14
remote: -----> Installing pip
remote: -----> Installing requirements with pip
remote:        Collecting altgraph==0.10.2 (from -r /tmp/build_a73484ff05f07a99f75f8542f74b80fe/requirements.txt (line 1))
remote:          Downloading altgraph-0.10.2.tar.gz (481kB)
remote:        Collecting backports.shutil-get-terminal-size==1.0.0 (from -r /tmp/build_a73484ff05f07a99f75f8542f74b80fe/requirements.txt (line 2))
remote:          Downloading backports.shutil_get_terminal_size-1.0.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl
remote:        Collecting bdist-mpkg==0.5.0 (from -r /tmp/build_a73484ff05f07a99f75f8542f74b80fe/requirements.txt (line 3))
remote:          Downloading bdist_mpkg-0.5.0.tar.gz
remote:        Collecting bonjour-py==0.3 (from -r /tmp/build_a73484ff05f07a99f75f8542f74b80fe/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:          Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement bonjour-py==0.3 (from -r /tmp/build_a73484ff05f07a99f75f8542f74b80fe/requirements.txt (line 4)) (from versions: )
remote:        No matching distribution found for bonjour-py==0.3 (from -r /tmp/build_a73484ff05f07a99f75f8542f74b80fe/requirements.txt (line 4))
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Python app.
remote: 
remote:  !     Push failed
remote: Verifying deploy...
remote: 
remote: !   Push rejected to magghy.
remote: 
To https://git.heroku.com/magghy.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://git.heroku.com/magghy.git'
```

Please, can you help me? I already created a Procfile with only this string:

```
worker: python magghybot.py
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved, with a command `touch Procfile`. This command created a file without extension, so I put my string `worker: python magghybot.py`. :)